# How to order factors in ggplot depending on two attributes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder this barplot based on the total count of male+female by each var1 levels. However, I am doing something wrong with `fct_reorder` and right now it's reordering only based on the value of `total` for `male`.

```
library(fct_relabel)
ff <- data.frame(var1=c('a','a','b','b'), var2=c('male', 'female', 'male', 'female'), total=c(40, 60, 30, 90)) 
          ggplot(data= ff, aes(x = fct_reorder(var1, total), y=total, fill=var2)) + 
          geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `sum` function in `fct_reorder`: by default it uses the median of the `total` values instead of the sum:

```
ggplot(data= ff, aes(x = fct_reorder(var1, total, sum), y=total, fill=var2)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```